# HTML & CSS Image Not Staying Inside Box

Tags: html, css

Recently I've been trying to make a game page on my website where it displays my icons, and all my games where you can click them. But recently I have been having trouble with sizing, and keeping them inside the *"Box"* or *"Outline"* I have made using CSS.

Here is my CSS Code (For the boxes):

```css
.outline {
    position: absolute;
    height:90%;
    top:30%;
    left:6%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.9) inset;
    background: url("../assets/backg.png") no-repeat center;
    background-color: #3156a0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: all 0.7s;
}

/* OUTLINE GAME LINKS  */
.gamelinkss {
   top:15%;
   left:6%;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
       <!-- BOX WITH LINKS -->
        <div class = "outline">
             <!-- LINKS -->
            <div class="gamelinkss">

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/1076861807/Cocoa-Demo-CHAPTER-8">
                    <img alt = "Cocoa" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/CocoaIcon.jpg"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/5270744430/Vibe-House">
                    <img alt = "Vibe" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/VIBEHOUSE%20ICON.png"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/4464933320/Beat-Saber-ALPHA">
                    <img alt = "Saber" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/beat%20saber%20icon%20finished.jpg"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/5027869898/Ninjago-Tycoon-NEW">
                    <img alt = "Ninjago" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/Ninjago%20Icon.png"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/5693597867/Sniper-Simulator-Advanced">
                    <img alt = "Sniper" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/SNIPER%20ICON%20FINAL.png"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/5651722790/Coconut-Tycoon-NEW">
                    <img alt = "Tycoon" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/CocoonutTycoonIcon.jpg"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/5100410493/Freddy-ALPHA">
                    <img alt = "Freddy" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/freddyicon.png"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/5431394008/TwinPlayzDev-YTs-Place-Number-37">
                    <img alt = "StarWars" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/New%20Logo.jpg"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/4990774541/Moonlight-Clicker-Remastered">
                    <img alt = "CaseClick" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/CaseCLICKICON.jpg"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

            </div>
             <!-- STYLE -->
            <p style = "color: transparent;"></p>
        </div>
```

Could this be because I'm setting `width` and `height` in HTML?

I am still struggling and wondering. I want to get these games to all fit along inside the box, and then make it so each icon will shrink with the box when needed to. So I guess you can say its not fitting inside the *"OUTLINE"* box.

Link to website if you would like to see : https://constantinelinardakis.github.io/OfficialWebsite/Games.html

Comment: you have given max-width: 500px to the class gamelinkss

Comment: if you want your outline box height adjusts as the number of games you can add `height: auto` -- OR -- if you want there should be scrolling  inside the box for the games you can do `overflow-y: scroll`

Comment: I still don't understand what you need. Do you want the box to scroll if you have too many icons?

Comment: @maxshuty I am trying to making the box stay the same height as it already is so below and above the footer and header so its all fits. But then the images/icons automatically fit inside that box and either if I keep adding more boxes I can try overflow-y:scroll or try something where the boxes just fit and get scaled down inside the box.

Comment: @ConstantineLinardakis got it. The solution I posted with CSS grid should suit you well. Take the parent container and add `overflow-y: scroll` for scrolling and you should be good to go. Personally I would shy away from having things scale depending on how many you put in there as your app will suddenly have a different feel to it every time you add something to it once it's maxed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should be a good start for what you're trying to do. You should look more into [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/):

```
.gamelinkcss {
  padding: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}
```

This will create an auto-wrapping `grid` inside of your container. For this I've set each grid item to be `200px`, you may need to adjust it to fit your needs.

You will still need to set the `overflow` to `hidden` or `scroll` depending on your needs. You will also need to adjust the blue background parent container element to fit nicely but this should get you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```css
.outline {
    position: absolute;
    height:fit-content;
    width:100%;
    top:30%;
    left:6%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.9) inset;
    background: url("../assets/backg.png") no-repeat center;
    background-color: #3156a0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: all 0.7s;
    
    
    
}

/* OUTLINE GAME LINKS  */
.gamelinkss {
   top:15%;
   left:6%;
   height: 100%;
   width: 500px;
}
```

```html
       <!-- BOX WITH LINKS -->
        <div class = "outline">
             <!-- LINKS -->
            <div class="gamelinkss">

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/1076861807/Cocoa-Demo-CHAPTER-8">
                    <img alt = "Cocoa" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/CocoaIcon.jpg"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/5270744430/Vibe-House">
                    <img alt = "Vibe" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/VIBEHOUSE%20ICON.png"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/4464933320/Beat-Saber-ALPHA">
                    <img alt = "Saber" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/beat%20saber%20icon%20finished.jpg"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/5027869898/Ninjago-Tycoon-NEW">
                    <img alt = "Ninjago" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/Ninjago%20Icon.png"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/5693597867/Sniper-Simulator-Advanced">
                    <img alt = "Sniper" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/SNIPER%20ICON%20FINAL.png"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/5651722790/Coconut-Tycoon-NEW">
                    <img alt = "Tycoon" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/CocoonutTycoonIcon.jpg"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/5100410493/Freddy-ALPHA">
                    <img alt = "Freddy" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/freddyicon.png"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/5431394008/TwinPlayzDev-YTs-Place-Number-37">
                    <img alt = "StarWars" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/New%20Logo.jpg"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.roblox.com/games/4990774541/Moonlight-Clicker-Remastered">
                    <img alt = "CaseClick" src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/OfficialWebsite/main/src/assets/CaseCLICKICON.jpg"
                    style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                </a>

            </div>
             <!-- STYLE -->
            <p style = "color: transparent;"></p>
        </div>
```